# How to aggregate on percentiles in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to be able to aggregate based on percentiles (or more accurate in my case, complement percentiles)

Consider the following code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ['a', 1,    'w'],
        ['a', 1,    'y'],
        ['a', 11,   'x'],
        ['a', 111,  'zzz'],
        ['a', 1111, 'zz'],
        ['a', 1111, 'zz'],
        ['b', 2,    'w'],
        ['b', 2,    'w'],
        ['b', 2,    'w'],
        ['b', 22,   'y'],
        ['b', 2222, 'x'],
        ['b', 2222, 'z'],
    ],
    ['grp', 'val1', 'val2'])

grouped = df.groupby('grp').agg(
        F.count('*').alias('count'),
        F.expr('percentile(val1, array(0.5, 0.75)) as percentiles'),
        # val2 manipulation....
    )

grouped.show()
```

In addition to the grouping and the percentiles calculation, I would like to count the distinct values of `val2` in the complement percentiles respectively.
For group `b` for example, the 50th percentile of `val1` is 12 and the complement percentile is the last 3 rows which contain 3 distinct values of `val2` (y,x,z).
Similarly, the 75th percentile of is 1672 and the complement percentile is the last 2 rows which contain 2 distinct values (x,z).

So my desired output would be:

```
+---+-----+--------------+--------------|
|grp|count|   percentiles|distinct count|
+---+-----+--------------+--------------|
|  a|    6| [61.0, 861.0]|[2, 1]        |
|  b|    6|[12.0, 1672.0]|[3, 2]        |
+---+-----+--------------+--------------|
```

How can I acheive this?

Comment: are you using spark 2.4+?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using 2.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For spark 2.3.2, you can use Window function to calculate percentiles, find `val2`s satisfying condition associated with percentiles and then do aggregation:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F

w1 = Window.partitionBy('grp')

df1 = df.withColumn('percentiles', F.expr('percentile(val1, array(0.5, 0.75))').over(w1)) \
    .withColumn('c1', F.expr('IF(val1>percentiles[0],val2,NULL)')) \
    .withColumn('c2', F.expr('IF(val1>percentiles[1],val2,NULL)'))

grouped = df1.groupby('grp').agg(
    F.count('*').alias('count'), 
    F.first('percentiles').alias('percentiles'), 
    F.array(F.countDistinct('c1'), F.countDistinct('c2')).alias('distinct_count')
)
grouped.show()
+---+-----+--------------+--------------+
|grp|count|   percentiles|distinct_count|
+---+-----+--------------+--------------+
|  b|    6|[12.0, 1672.0]|        [3, 2]|
|  a|    6| [61.0, 861.0]|        [2, 1]|
+---+-----+--------------+--------------+
```